# Setup Stripe Flutterflow

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I can't configure Stripe in Flutterflow. Has anyone had success?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXu6d.png)

I installed the stripe plugin on Firebase (Blaze plan) but the error persists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjVg.png)

Comment: Could you share more details of what you have tried?  Including some formatted code snippets will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions cannot be invoke if the user is not set up in permission. To allow the function to be called by all users, you need to add "allUsers" with permission to "invoke" the function in the permission tab of the function in Google Cloud Console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHXBA.png)

I hope that helped..